# overflow values in column of mysql-table

Tags: mysql

I have table with an id, timestamp and a byte-count-value. The value is limited to 4,294,967,295.

```
    +-------+---------------------+------------+------------+
    | id    | created             | received   | sent       |
    +-------+---------------------+------------+------------+
    | 18756 | 2017-07-02 10:14:00 | 3851926349 |      39421 |
    | 18755 | 2017-07-02 02:14:00 | 3851926349 | 4215449136 |
    +-------+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

The value resets to 0 if there is an overflow. How can I get the row with that overflow-event?

Comment: I guess you mean received and sent are int fields. Can you change to bigint? Or are you trying to catch those which go over the int maximum value on an insert or update or on a query?

Comment: These values are records from a data source. This source data I can't change to bigint. I try to catch the rows which gone over the maximum.

Comment: Are these really rows from source or are they aggregations based on ID and created?

Comment: The data of received and sent is read from a device and saved in that database. The id and created column is created when a new row is inserted.

Comment: Then if does not overflow on the device you have to detect the overflow on the read before it is written to the db.

Comment: do know a possibility to read the overflow from the raw data out of the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a mysql-query

```
     SELECT `tNext`.*
     FROM `dsl_connection` AS `t1`
     JOIN `dsl_connection` AS `tNext` ON `tNext`.`id` = `t1`.`id` + 1
     WHERE `tNext`.`sent` < `t1`.`sent`
     ORDER BY `t1`.`id` DESC
     LIMIT 10
```